# On triviality and numerical triviality of (classes of) divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors

Let $X$ be a smooth irreducible threefold, and let $H$ be an ample divisor on $X$. 
Assume that $D$ is a divisor on $X$ such that $D\cdot H^2=D^2\cdot H=D^3=0$.

Question 1: Is $D$ numerically trivial?

Question 2: Is $D$ trivial?

Actually, the argument at page 69 (section 3.8) in the book [O. Debarre, Higher-Dimensional Algebraic Geometry] should answer yes to the first question, but I don't understand it. (For example, it seems that he applies the Hodge index theorem also in the case of singular surfaces.)

I hope someone can give me some clarification.

Comment: Am not sure what you are asking. Are you asking an explanation of Debarre's proof for question 1? Clearly, Q2 can not be true since any numerically trivial divisor has the property you state, but there are many numerically trivial divisors which are not trivial.

Comment: Question 1 indeed follows from the argument on page 69 of Debarre. I agree that it has to be argued that the surface $Y$ considered there can be taken to be regular, but this is supplied by Bertini. Question 2 is meaningless as remarked by Mohan.

Comment: From Bertini it follows that $Y$ is smooth outside the curve $C$ taken there, but $Y$ could be singular on $C$. Isn't it?

Comment: You are right that one needs to be more careful. It seems to me that one could reduce to the case that $C$ is smooth and then use the argument from the footnote on page 32 to ensure that $Y$ could be taken smooth a well. I have to run now, but just an idea to try (if it makes sense).

Comment: I just saw on the book SGA 6 (Expose VIII) that the Hodge index theorem is true for irreducible surfaces (not necessary smooth). So now I understand (almost completely) the Debarre's argument. Thank you for your help.